# Почему "россияне", а не "российцы"?

Tags: этимология, этноним

Почему граждане России - россияне, а не российцы?

Answer (score 1):

А почему они должны быть российцами?

Англ**ия** - англичане, Грец**ия** - греки, Итал**ия** - итальянцы, Франц**ия** - французы...

Comment: Пруссия-пруссияне или пруссы, украина-украиняне,переберите все страны европы, поэтому и вопрос по России, откуда окончание яне, от славяне,т.е славные яне...))))

Comment: Англия-англияне, греция- грецияне, италия-итальяне, франция-францияне... Вы поняли свой ответ, лично я не нашёл связи с вопросом

Comment: Как можно было не понять, что приведены примеры, где у всех названий стран в конце — "ия", а у названий граждан — разные суффиксы?
С какой стати брать только страны, только Европу?
Варшавяне, галилеяне, киевляне, филистимляне, армяне, гаитяне, египтяне...

Answer (score 0):

Наверно, всё дело в благозвучии. Казахстанцы - хорошо, но российцы - не очень. Кыргызцы - не звучит, а немцы ещё как!

Answer (score 0):

Это весьма необычная и неочевидная история.
Нельзя сравнивать с названиями жителями других стран, они почти всегда означают и гражданство (подданство) и национальность. Не беру Америку, там спорный вопрос о существовании национальности "американец", а из остальных близких к нам народов относительно "правильным" способом разделения жителя и титульной национальности могут похвастаться, кажется, только латыши-латвийцы.

В России этого способа никогда не было. До 1917 г. русскими называли всех жителей Российской империи (в случаях, когда это не вызывало путаницы, иначе говорили о подданных Российской Короны). Слово же "россиянин" существовало, но относилось к "высокому стилю", оно и было образовано по образцу названий жителей местности(ср. московитянин от московит). Когда же в современных реалиях понадобилось четко разграничить граждан России и русских по национальности было востребовано единственное известное (но хорошо подзабытое) слово. По достаточно общему мнению, это возрождение "россиянина" обязано Борису Николаевичу Ельцину в бытность его первым Президентом Росиии.